# they live on the streets of our city

Tags: pronouns, nouns

a. I have found out something about bears. They live in the forest near our town.

(Some of them live in the forest near out town.)

===========================

b. Tom and Harry were talking about old books. They were in their father's library.

(Some old books were in their father's library.)

===========================

c. We need to learn more about rats. They live on the streets of our city.

(There are rats living on the streets of our city.)

Are (a), (b) and (c) grammatically correct and do the convey the right meaning?

Comment: I would understand (b) to mean that Tom and Harry were in the library.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kate. I see the problem. So (a) and (c) are fine, right?

Comment: Yes, _they_ can be understood to mean _members of the species_.